# How to create multiple blocks for blog teasers from a single view automatically

Tags: views, blocks

I have created a site whose home page is built in a way that it will display 4 latest blog posts in separate blocks all the time.

I have created a view and successfully created a single block displaying one latest blog post, but I am not sure what to do to get the other 3 blocks generated automatically. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly - In views, create a new block for each instance of the block you want by clicking on +Add:

You could also create a completely new view, but this keeps things organized.

[image]

Where you put in the number of items to display, you can change the **offset** of the item:

[image]

In this way you can set the second block to have an offset of 1, the third 2, and so on. You can then create 4 blocks that each contain one of the most recent 4 items.

Comment: I think you guys mis-understood the question. I know how to add block in a view as I already stated I have already created one block displaying my latest blog post teaser.

But the problem is that, I need it to automatically create another block when a new blog post is made to display its teaser in that block.

Comment: if there is a limit to the number of blocks needed, you can use the information already provided - it would simply produce empty blocks until sufficient content existed to populate them. If there is no limit, then you need to look into writing a custom module.

Comment: You may be right, however lets consider it to be 4 blocks only needed. So in that case is there an option for me to make it work something like this:
---
Block one: display 4th last post
---
Block two: display 3rd last post
---
Block three: display 2nd last post
---
Block Four: display latest post

Comment: yes - if there's no content, it shouldn't render the individual block. It only becomes an issue if you want a variable number of blocks to display

Comment: One last thing coming to my mind... How can I seperate content in each block. For example i can set filter for content type, but in this case I only have one common content type so the content rendered in 4 blocks can be same. Is there a way we can tell it to be different?

Comment: that's where the offset I mention in my answer comes in to play - it tells the view which content to show. Set each block to have a different offset value

Comment: You are the man :-) Solved my problem :) I wonder why i never ever before used this option. Its great!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 3 more blocks similar to that one, you could go to the view using the view UI, and clone the one you already have, setting the proper offset to the other three.

For cloning a display (in your case a block), you go to your view, click on the block link, once you are seeing your display you should see another link (select list) on the top-right of your screen. 
First item on this select list is "Clone [your display name]" (the others are "delete" and "disable").

But I'm not sure if you want that. "Automatically" is a little ambigous term.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is actually, I need it to automatically create another block when a new blog post is made to display its teaser in that block.